# animate() not working when providing an object

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to animate my header after scrolling 120px. This code is working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery(window).on('scroll', function() {
    scrollPosition = jQuery(this).scrollTop();
    if (scrollPosition >= 120) {
      jQuery(".add-header-height").css("height", "90");
      jQuery(".add-header-height").addClass("sticky");
    } else {
      jQuery(".add-header-height").css("height", "120");
      jQuery(".add-header-height").removeClass("sticky");
    }
  });
});
```

If I change  `.css("height", "90");` to `.animate({ height: 90 });`
and `.css("height", "120");` to `.animate({ height: 120 });` then the code doesn't work any more. Add and removeClass works fine, but the animation does not. Why?

Comment: You need to include the units: `{ height: '50px' }`

Comment: thx for your edit! i changed it to `.animate({height:'90px'})` but still doesn't work. i see my sticky class is come and gone how it should work. but the hight do what he wants. some time 120px some time 90px, but not accurate with the class.